# Increase variable count only if it has same value on some elements of array - PHP

Tags: php

I don't know either its the correct title for this question. Please, help me to edit this question if I am not adding appropriate title.

I am trying to work with hall space booking for event. There are three types of space booking:

```
Full - 0 (Can book by one team at same time)
Half - 1 (Can book by 2 team at same time)
Shared - 2 (Can book by 4 teams at same time)
```

So, I write following mention code.

```
<?php 

$obj0 = new stdClass();
$obj0->id = '1';
$obj0->start = '2019-06-28';
$obj0->end = '2019-06-28';
$obj0->start_time = '07:00:00';
$obj0->end_time = '08:00:00';
$obj0->hall_space = '1';

$obj1 = new stdClass();
$obj1->id = '7';
$obj1->start = '2019-06-28';
$obj1->end = '2019-06-28';
$obj1->start_time = '06:00:00';
$obj1->end_time = '07:00:00';
$obj1->hall_space = '1';

$obj2 = new stdClass();
$obj2->id = '2';
$obj2->start = '2019-06-29';
$obj2->end = '2019-06-29';
$obj2->start_time = '07:00:00';
$obj2->end_time = '08:00:00';
$obj2->hall_space = '1';

$obj3 = new stdClass();
$obj3->id = '8';
$obj3->start = '2019-06-29';
$obj3->end = '2019-06-29';
$obj3->start_time = '06:00:00';
$obj3->end_time = '07:00:00';
$obj3->hall_space = '1';

$obj4 = new stdClass();
$obj4->id = '3';
$obj4->start = '2019-06-30';
$obj4->end = '2019-06-30';
$obj4->start_time = '07:00:00';
$obj4->end_time = '08:00:00';
$obj4->hall_space = '1';

$obj5 = new stdClass();
$obj5->id = '9';
$obj5->start = '2019-06-30';
$obj5->end = '2019-06-30';
$obj5->start_time = '06:00:00';
$obj5->end_time = '07:00:00';
$obj5->hall_space = '1';

$data = array($obj0, $obj1, $obj2, $obj3, $obj4, $obj5);
$hall_space = 1; //this means user is trying to book half space



        if(count($data) > 0) {

            $half = 0;
            $shared = 0;
            $error = false;
            $looping_date = '';
            $same_date = 0;
            switch ($hall_space) {
                case '0':
                    echo "aa";
                    $error = true;
                    break;
                case '1':
                    foreach ($data as $dk => $dv) {
                        if($looping_date == $dv->start){
                            $same_date = $same_date + 1;
                        }else{
                            $same_date = 0;
                        }
                        if ($dv->hall_space == 0) {
                            echo "bb";
                            $error = true;
                        } elseif ($dv->hall_space == 1) {
                            $half = $half + 1;
                            if ($half == 2) {
                                echo "cc";
                                $error = true;
                            }
                        } elseif ($dv->hall_space == 3) {
                            $shared = $shared + 1;
                            if ($shared == 2) {
                                echo "dd";
                                $error = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case '2':
                    foreach ($data as $dk => $dv) {
                        if ($dv->hall_space == 0) {
                            echo "ee";
                            $error = true;
                        } elseif ($dv->hall_space == 1) {
                            $half = $half + 1;
                            if ($half == 2) {
                                echo "ff";
                                $error = true;
                            }
                        } elseif ($dv->hall_space == 2) {
                            $shared = $shared + 1;
                            if ($shared == 3) {
                                echo "gg";
                                $error = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        if( isset($error) ){
            echo "error";
        }else{
            echo "not error";
        }
```

This was working fine for a singe event (i.e non-repeating). But, this is not working correctly for repeating events.

Here, in this scenario user trying to book half-space(i.e value 1) for date `2019-06-28` to `2019-06-30` from `6 am to 8am`.

Above mentioned `$data` represents all the already booked events for that time frame, that means on every day there are are two half-spaced events (one from 6-7am and next from 7-8am) on each day. Which means this new events (half-spaced) should be allowed to book.

But, my logic is not working because, it is considering all those events as they are going to held in same date and time.**That means, `$half` variable should be increased only if the events are on same date and time** and finally should not generate error.

I tried to explain everything from myside, also you can just copy and paste the code for test. And, let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: You've overengineered this. You just need a single array which relates hour long periods to how full the hall is for that hour. Then just check each hour and see if there is space.

Comment: Also you have no kind of input alongside $hall_space to say when the user is trying to book for. I'd also scrap the full=0, half=1 and shared=2 and instead just use those strings. Map the strings as constants to the numerical space they take up where 1 is full, 0 is empty. Or don't have any human readable representation at all and just use a 0-1 value straight up to say how much space they will use.

Comment: @shardj I could not understand what you are trying to say, could you elaborate your idea as an answer?. Also, I have mentioned there, user is trying to book from `06:00:00` to `08:00:00` and all the data received above are the data which could create conflict in booking during this period. And, what do you mean by just 1 for full and 0 for empty.

Comment: I posted an answer, I didn't write out most of the code because If I was doing this properly I'd be using a database and custom classes to make this way neater. But I hope it shows the better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bookings = [
    [
        'period' => new DatePeriod(
            new DateTime('2019-06-28 07:00:00'), 
            new DateInterval('PT1H'),
            new DateTime('2019-06-28 08:00:00')
        ),
        'byWho' => ['1' => 0.5, '2' => 0.5]
    ],
    [
        'period' => new DatePeriod(
            new DateTime('2019-06-28 08:00:00'), 
            new DateInterval('PT1H'),
            new DateTime('2019-06-28 09:00:00')
        ),
        'byWho' => ['2' => 0.5]
    ]
];
```

Example data structure, between 7 and 8 on 2019-06-28 team '1' booked half the hall. Between 7 and 9 team '2' booked half the hall. All bookings should be 1 hour, if they're longer than an hour such as team two then they actually have two bookings right next to each other. If 1 hour is too long then you can change the interval if you like.

So instead of having an array of who booked when which is what you have, instead here you have an array showing a timeline, you just need to look at a specific time to see if it's booked and how full it is.

This way is better than yours because you can easily keep those dates sorted, bring this data in and out of a database into this structure with ease. Now because it's sorted you can really easily find the time you're booking for and you only need to look at the space available for that time period. But for yours you need to check every single booking to see if there is space.

If you want to check if there is space for a specific time you can use a binary search (choose your own search if you want to make this easier) to find an intersecting DatePeriod, then check values either side to find any other matching date periods. Then you simply do a check to see if in those periods there's space to fit the booking. To check for space it's as easy as summing up the values in 'byWho' + your booking size and see if it's greater than 1.

Comment: i read your answer, got little bit of idea but I could not understand it fully. Does this mean, I need to restructure database? Or I just need to create an array as in above mentioned structure. Also, would it provide me flexibilty to increase or decrease total no. of shared space. i.e currently for shared it is 4 but can I keep changing to 3/4 based on different hall.

Comment: Also, I have tried to see what it looks using your code. So, just copy and paste your code and tried to `print_r($bookings)` it shows following errors:
`-  Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (P1H)`

`- Exception: DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (P1H)`

Comment: Sorry it's PT not P, I'll fix the error. But that was just an example. My point was that you shouldn't have an array which focuses on each item being a booking. Each item should be a time slot. Without seeing your database I couldn't tell you if you need to restructure that, that's a different question really.

Comment: And yes it increases flexibility for the amount of space used. Since full is represented by 1 you can use any fraction to show how much space is being taken.

Comment: Although, I have made few tweaks on your suggestion, I am accepting this as the answer. Basically, I fragment every chunk exactly to 1 hour slot, and store someting like `timestamp => space_occupied` and add space occupied value if the timestamp is same and save `4 - full, 2 -shared, 1 half` and checked either value for any time stamp is equal to 4 or not and handle the request based on that results.